# Linq2DB Add Property to Model

Tags: linq2db

Consider a simple model class and repository like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Column, Nullable] public string Username { get; set; }
    [Column, Nullable] public string Status { get; set; }
    [Column, Nullable] public bool Expired { get; set; }
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public IQueryable<User> Get(IDataContext context)
    {
        using (context)
        {
            return context.GetTable<User>();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to add an additional property to the instances of the `User` class on reads, but this property is not needed on updates or inserts. The desired model would look something like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Column, Nullable] public string Username { get; set; }
    [Column, Nullable] public string Status { get; set; }
    [Column, Nullable] public bool Expired { get; set; }

    public string HostName {get; set;}
}
```

Essentially I'd like to pass in a hostname value provided by the caller that will travel with the objects. I can do this by using a select statement in my repo class:

```
using (context)
{
    return from user in context.GetTable<User>()
           select new User()
           {
               Username = user.Username,
               Status   = user.Status,
               Expired  = user.Expired,
               Hostname = hostName
           }
}
```

But this feels wrong, and I'm not sure I want to do this in my repo anyway. Also, many of my POCO classes have a large number of properties and this will be a eyesore. Is there an idiomatic in Linq2DB way to add an arbitrary property to objects retrieved from the DB? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably can look at `OnEntityCreated` event of context. Something like that:

```cs
context.OnEntityCreated += args =>
{
    if (arg.Entity is IHostable hostable)
    {
        // I see problem here - where to get hostName itself
        // because context anyway is not multithreaded, it could
        // be a field of current context
        hostable.Hostname = context._hostName;
        // or
        hostable.Hostname = ((IHostProvider)ars.DataContext).HostName;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can I assume this is guidance around how to find the hostname value? I suppose I didn't ask the question clearly - I'm not attempting to find the hostname, I'm looking for a better implementation pattern that is idiomatic to Linq or Linq2DB. Maybe a simpler way to ask the question would be:

"Is there a way to set a property in the Linq query on reads that won't affect inserts and updates? Or is there a native Linq2DB feature that supports additional or synthetic properties on model objects?"

Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm lost. My answer shows how to initialize materialized entity with additional values. If you just want to read value from db, but not allow user to insert/update it - mark your property as readonly in mapping using `SkipOnUpdate` \ `SkipOnInsert` column attribute properties

Comment: I think I get what you're saying now, just can't get it working! I'll keep at it. Thanks!